# Accidently deleted files in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, hosting, cpanel

I was trying to install a poll extension on a joomla 2.5 site and was getting a http 500 error. I stupidly decided to delete the extension files from the server using cPanel file manager... I accidently deleted simplepie thinking it was part of the extension and its not causing http 500 errors with my Joom Gallery extension.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to restore the system files I deleted?

Comment: In cPanel there is Backup and Restore check for backup and download it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a local copy of Joomla + the extensions you deleted, and then use ftp to restore them to the server; in the future, try to use Joomla extension manager to install/uninstall extensions.

Comment: Thanks, had a copy of the site locally on my computer and was able to copy the deleted folder over. Usually I do uninstall using the manager, had an error that thought that pieces of the extensions and remained on the server. Good mistake to learn from though :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Deleted files in the cPanel File Manager as far as I know don't go to any trash folder. You should regularly take full backups of your site just incase things like this happen. You can also talk to your host, who should have a backup of the folder you deleted. They might however ask that you pay a small fee for this service, depending on the host.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I believe that your hoster has the backup. You need to pay restoration fee and I hope that will solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just deleted simplepie go grab a zip file of the joomla install and get it from there.